# Switching to Oracle Java?

Tags: google-chrome, java, centos-7, java-web-start

I am on CentOS 7.

By default, it comes with OpenJDK and icedtea.  Then I installed Oracle's JDK 7 rpm (from its official website)

When I try to open a jnlp file through chrome, chrome always uses icedtea to launch although I have configured alternatives to use Oracle's javaws (as well as java, javac, and jar although irrelevant here). If I yum-remove icedtea, chrome doesn't know how to open a jnlp and just keeps downloading whenever I click "keep".

Any idea how I can force chrome to associate jnlp files with javaws I set in the alternatives?

Thanks in advance.